# CLisp error: "(x) is not number"

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, infix-notation, clisp, infix-operator

This is my function that's supposed to implement infix evaluation for * and + operations.

```
(defun calculate(l)
    (cond
        ((eql (cadr l) '+) (+ (car l) (cddr l)))
        ((eql (cadr l) '*) (- (car l) (cddr l)))
    )
)
```

When I run this with the list '(3 + 4) it gives me an error saying "(4) is not a number". Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: There are functions with easier to understand names: CAR is better FIRST. CADR is better SECOND. CADDR is better THIRD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part with `(cddr l)` should be `(caddr l)`. You have to access the first element of the list, not the list. The code should be then:

```
(defun calculate(l)
    (cond
        ((eql (cadr l) '+) (+ (car l) (caddr l)))
        ((eql (cadr l) '*) (- (car l) (caddr l)))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Symbols can be called as functions. Thus your code is just this:

```
(defun calculate (l)
  (funcall (second l) (first l) (third l)))
```

or

```
(defun calculate (l)
  (destructuring-bind (arg1 op arg2)
      l
    (funcall op arg1 arg2)))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 77 > (calculate '(20 + 30))
50
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but note that in the original code only + and - are allowed... Additional code should be provided to check that just the supported operations are passed to `funcall`. Something along the lines of `(and (member op '(+ -)) (funcall op...)`.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla: sure, he can add it. Shouldn't be too difficult.